# "if debug" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Is there anything in JavaScript or Visual Studio to detect if the code is used in debug-mode?
Something like "#if DEBUG" in C#, but for JavaScript?

Comment: `if (debug)` would work just fine if you define `debug` when in debug mode.  It would be up to you to define that as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

`#if`/`#endif` are preprocessor directives in C# (and other languages) that tells the compiler to conditionally include/exclude a section of code when compiling.

JavaScript is a script language that is not precompiled, and therefore it would not make much sense to have preprocessor directives like these.

Comment: On the other hand, you can set variables for example from a master page or layout page in case of MCV project. So if your js file has a publicly available variable (not in closure) eg MyNamespace{debugmode: true, MyFunction: function(){ if(MyNamespace.debugmode){console.log("debug mode!");}}} if you set the "debugmode" to false, you're in release mode. You can set this variable from  an aspx/cshtml file where you can use build directives depending on the debug/release build mode. The drawback is you expose the js variable which can be modified from browser console too by anyone.

Comment: Some javascript "compilers" (or minifiers, transformers, whatever they are called) may have this feature. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2935165/1003746

Answer (score 11):

A bit late, but I needed the same and could not give up until a viable solution.

I have a kind of "main" javascript file, where I have a line like:

```
Site.DEBUG = false;
```

Then in the code I can check for this constant. Now I needed to solve that at build time, some automation would set this for me according to project configuration. Here I've found [fnr.exe](https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/) command-line tool for find and replace in files. It's a quite good piece of utility, would be worth to check out anyway. So at this point I've created a folder in the project directory called `BuildScripts`, I've copied the `fnr.exe` file into it, and created a batch file like this.

```
switch_client_debug.bat

REM Params: path to folder, filename, change-DEBUG-from-this, to-this
fnr.exe --cl --dir "%1" --fileMask "%2" --caseSensitive --showEncoding --find "DEBUG = %3" --replace "DEBUG = %4"
```

Then I defined the corresponding pre-build events at the web project like this:

```
cd $(ProjectDir)BuildScripts
call switch_client_debug.bat $(ProjectDir)ts site.ts false true
```

and its pair at Release config:

```
cd $(ProjectDir)BuildScripts
call switch_client_debug.bat $(ProjectDir)ts site.ts true false
```

Now everything works like a charm and I can have logging, tracing, special logic for Debug and for Release configuration in Javascript.

Comment: As a follow-up, I have to add the comment that I actually don't use this workaround for a long time. Instead there are several better tools like `gulp` and plugins for scenarios similar to these. However, if one doesn't have an `npm` environment set up, it can be still an acceptable option.

Answer (score 3):

Only for IE there is the conditional compilation:

```
/*@cc_on
@set @version = @_jscript_version
@if (@_win32)
document.write("You are running 32 bit IE " + @version);
@elif (@win_16)
document.write("You are running 16 bit IE " + @version);
@else @*/
document.write("You are running another browser or an old IE.");
/*@end @*/
```

[nice article here](http://triin.net/2011/11/02/IE_Conditional_Compilation)

Comment: Thank you, but I would need a cross-browser-solution.

Answer (score 0):

Late in the party, but here is what I do on Visual Studio

```
// #region Uncomment when in debug mode
// localStorage.clear();
// #endregion
```